# Telethon: Can I use two filters in iter_message?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

Hi I want to make a bot that downloads all the media from a chat ignoring stickers or text messages. The problem is that I can only use one filter at a time.

I tried using logic operators and tuples, but they didn't work.

I read that I can use also the type() function instead of the telethon's filters, but I don't understand how. Can someone help me?

These are my attempts:

```
python
    async for message in client.iter_messages(chat,
         reverse=True, filter=InputMessagesFilterDocument and InputMessagesFilterMusic):
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat,
         reverse=True, filter=InputMessagesFilterDocument or InputMessagesFilterMusic):


async for message in client.iter_messages(chat,
             reverse=True, filter=(InputMessagesFilterDocument, InputMessagesFilterMusic)):
```

Comment: No, Telegram's API does not support such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Telegram **doesn't** allow multiple filters on API request, so you'll need to ignore text messages and sticker after receiving the message. To do that you can use the following code.

```
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
      if message.media and not message.sticker:
        #do your things
```

This way with `message.media` you check if the message contains any media and with `not message.sticker` you check if the media contained into the message is a sticker.